# How can two people read the same book on different devices

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, books

I have bought a book on iBooks and my girlfriend also wants to read it. But I was wondering if it would cause any problems regarding icloud remembering where one of us stopped reading.

I have tried searching online but I couldn't find anything that would help. I was thinking about letting her use the bookmark function but that might cause me to lose my point in the book.

Is there any way we can easily read the same book on the same account? Preferably we should be able to use the same device but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you considered adding her as part of the "family" ?

Did this with iTunes and my daughter, but a quick look in the help in iBooks shows that you can share a book via family without compromising either Apple Id...

Comment: I will try that. If its a good solution and no better solution arise i will accept this answer.